# Dynamic navbar based on section tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a dynamic single page website were I'm using `<section>` as a way to hold different pages. Then with jquery I'm hiding every section until a link is clicked. I was able to get this working by explicitly adding the links and sections, but my issue is trying to make it dynamic by using a jquery loop.

These are how I need the links to look when outputted:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li data-index="1"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li data-index="2"><a href="#">Multiple Choice</a></li>
  <li data-index="3"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery that hides and shows the section based off what link is clicked:

```
  $('.nav li').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
        $('.content').hide();
        $('section[data-index="'+index+'"]').show();
        $('h1').addClass('animated bounce');
  });
```

Now the part were I'm having trouble, building the navbar dynamically with jQuery. This is what I have so far:

I create the actual navbar structure:

```
var nav = '<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse" role="navigation"> <div class="container"> <div class="navbar-header"> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-target="0" id="scroll">Thinking Cap Create</a> </div> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav">  </ul> </div> </div> </nav>'
```

Then I append the navbar to the body:

```
$('body').append(nav);
```

But now this is were things get weird. I tried creating a loop based off how many sections there are on a page and increase each link by 1.

```
$('section').each(function(i,v) { if(i < $('section').length) { var nav = $('<li data-index="'+(i)+'><a href="#"' + ($(this).children().attr('name'))+'</li>'); $('.nav navbar-nav').append(nav);}});
```

But this isn't working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What happens? Are any of the nav items being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector `$('.nav navbar-nav')` is wrong. It should be:

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav').append(nav)
```

Comment: I can see things being outputted now. Although the links that are being made look like this: `<li data-index="2><a href=" #"page2< li></li>`

Comment: Your `a` tag is incomplete. Should be: `'<a href="#">' + ($(this).children().attr('name'))+'</a>'`